# pack of cigarettes, carton of cigarettes

Tags: português-brasileiro, tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia

I am studying how to say *pack of cigarettes* and *carton of cigarettes* in Brazilian Portuguese.

Here is what I already have:

[Image of pack of cigarettes](http://www.hypermotoshop.cz/image/cache/data/kapesni-digitalni-vaha-200g-001g-manlloro-77-500x500.JPG)

Suggestions: pacote de cigarros, maço de cigarros, carteira de cigarros

[Image of carton of cigarettes](http://img2.hyperinzerce.cz/x-cz/inz/10401/10401483-prodam-kartony-cigaret-a-tabaku-marlboro-camel-atd-za-690kc-7.jpg)

Suggestions: pacotes de cigarros, pacote de maços de cigarro

Could you please help me to finish it?

Comment: @James Não sei se não estamos a violar alguma lei sobre a publicidade ao tabaco :)

Comment: Você está certo, melhor deixar apenas o link mesmo. Já voltei ao normal :)

Comment: @James Lol, na verdade eu tava a brincar.

Comment: @Jacinto, pois eu acreditei na brincadeira então... hehe.Podia ser alguma regra que eu não conhecia...

Answer (score 7):

A ***pack** of cigarettes* is a ***maço** de cigarros* [(see *maço* in Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/ma%C3%A7o), and a ***carton*** is a ***pacote***. These words are used both in Brasil and Portugal. Examples of actual usage:

> Um pacote com dez maços de cigarros da marca que gosta, que no Brasil sai por R$ 67, custa R$ 150 na Alemanha. [[*Globo.com*]](http://oglobo.globo.com/economia/com-precos-mais-baixos-que-no-exterior-cigarro-vira-suvenir-de-turistas-no-brasil-13180517)
>
> Cada caixa de cigarros continha 50 pacotes de 10 maços. No total foram apreendidos mais de 117 mil maços de cigarros avaliados em R$100 mil pela polícia. [[ZH Notícias]](http://zh.clicrbs.com.br/rs/noticias/noticia/2012/04/mais-de-117-mil-macos-de-cigarros-contrabandeados-sao-apreendidos-em-lajeado-3738223.html)

Now, [*pacote* (Aulete 1)](http://www.aulete.com.br/pacote) is a very general word; its nearest English equivalent is [*package* (Oxford Learner's)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/package_1?q=package). In the two examples above it is very clear what the *pacote* is, but without clear context people might be unsure. For instance in the title of [this article in *Tempo*](http://www.otempo.com.br/interessa/sa%C3%BAde-e-ci%C3%AAncia/pacote-de-cigarro-ter%C3%A1-novo-aviso-sobre-riscos-do-fumo-1.1019118), —“Pacote de cigarro terá novo aviso sobre riscos do fumo”—*pacote* appears to mean *maço*. So if the context is not very clear you may want to say *pacote de maços de cigarros*.

Comment: but if I search pacote on Google for images I get this: https://www.google.cz/search?q=pacote&biw=1477&bih=675&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjls9K5neXPAhVFrRQKHdUsB6IQ_AUIBigB and there is no cigarette. Is "pacote de maços de cigarro m" better than?

Comment: @cornejo "Pacote de maços de cigarros" is  very clear. Everybody knows what a *maço de cigarros* is, but many people may be unsure of what a *pacote de cigarros* is, as not everyone buys cigarros by the pacote. And yes, *pacote* is a very general word, just like *carton*. If you google *carton* you will also get lots of different types of cartons.

Comment: @cornejo if you search for "pacote", of course you don't get anything related to cigarretes. You get the same results as if you search for "carton"! But if you search for "pacote de cigarros" or for "cigarrete carton", **then** you will find what you expected.

Comment: @cornejo you can try the pt-PT version ["volumes de tabaco"](https://www.google.pt/search?q=volume+de+tabaco&newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&hs=0uv&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_mIXxoefPAhXGXBQKHd06B1MQ_AUICCgB&biw=1624&bih=925)

Answer (score 3):

## Portuguese

Em português de Portugal (pt-PT), o mais usado, pelo menos no norte, é "tabaco"
(tobacco) em vez de "cigarros" e "volume" em vez de "pacote":

- **maço de tabaco**   (pack of cigarettes)
- **volume de tabaco** (carton of cigarettes)

Fica a resposta como complemento às outras em pt-BR.

---

## English

In **European Portuguese** we mostly use "tabaco"(tobacco) instead of "cigarros".

We say "maço de tabaco" when we want to refer a pack of cigarettes, and we say "volume de tabaco" when we want to refer a carton of cigarettes:

- **maço de tabaco**   (pack of cigarettes)
- **volume de tabaco** (carton of cigarettes)

If I wanted to ask you for a cigarette I would say: "Tens tabaco? Podes me arranjar um?".

This answer is a complement to the Brazilian Portuguese answers.

Comment: Aqui na zona de Lisboa, também é mais comum *maço de tabaco* que *maço de cigarros*.

Answer (score 2):

In **Brazilian Portuguese**, depending on where you are and who you are talking to, a pack of cigarettes can be called:

- **"um maço de cigarros"**, already mentioned in another answer.
- **"uma carteira de cigarros"**, which is current usage and just as common as "maço".

e.g. (a) Sr. Ferreira, quantos maços de cigarro o senhor está fumando atualmente?
(b) Bem,Dr, eu fumava duas carteiras de cigarros por dia mas já diminuí.

> - [As carteiras de cigarros devem conter advertências de que são nocivas à saúde, tal como é feito em outros países.](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=42QNnFzoKcMC&pg=PA32&dq=%22carteiras+de+cigarros%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR_vXtquXPAhVJhJAKHcn9AeoQ6AEINDAA#v=onepage&q=%22carteiras%20de%20cigarros%22&f=false)
> - [Quanta gente que diz que fuma duas carteiras de cigarros por dia, mas, na realidade, dá umas duas ou três tragadas e deixa o cigarro quase inteiro.](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=mVflDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT39&dq=%22carteiras+de+cigarros%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR_vXtquXPAhVJhJAKHcn9AeoQ6AEISTAE#v=onepage&q=%22carteiras%20de%20cigarros%22&f=false)

There are other terms but they are regional and not known to everyone in Brazil. As for a carton, it's always "um pacote de X"  e.g. "Por favor, eu quero um pacote de X".  At the moment you're buying, you simply mention what brand you want. Saying "Eu quero um pacote de maços de cigarros" sounds redundant.